# Post not working, Bindparam issues

Tags: php, mysql

My code seems the execute but only inserts empty values into my database. I know it has something to do with bindparam but I cannot understand where is the issue.

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include("post.php"); ?>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <form name="contact-form" action="post.php" method="post" id="contact-form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Nombre">Nombre</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Apellido">Apellido</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Sexo">Sexo</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="sexo" id="Sexo">
                                <option></option>
                                <option>Femenino</option>
                                <option>Masculino</option>
                                <option>Otro</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Civil">Estado Civil</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="civil" id="Civil">
                                <option></option>
                                <option>Soltero</option>
                                <option>Casado</option>
                                <option>Viudo</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Dni">DNI</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="dni" placeholder="DNI" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="fijo">Telefono Fijo</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fijo" placeholder="Fijo"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="celular">Telefono Celular</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="celular" placeholder="Celular"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="calle">Calle</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="calle" placeholder="Calle"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="ciudad">Ciudad</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ciudad" placeholder="Ciudad"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="provincia">Provincia</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="provincia" placeholder="Provincia"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="pais">Pais</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pais" placeholder="Pais"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="Objetivo">Objetivo</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="objetivo" placeholder="Objetivo"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="empresa">Empresa</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="empresa" placeholder="Empresa"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="actividad">Actividad de la Empresa</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="actividad" placeholder="Actividad de la Empresa"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="puesto">Puesto</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="puesto" placeholder="Puesto"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nivel">Categoria</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="categoria" placeholder="Categoria"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="pais">Pais</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lugar" placeholder="Pais"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="desde">Desde</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="desde" placeholder="Desde"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="hasta">Hasta</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="hasta" placeholder="Hasta"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="area">Area del Puesto</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="area" placeholder="area"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="descripcion">Descripcion</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descripcion" placeholder="Descripcion"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="personas">Personas a Cargo</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="personas" placeholder="Personas a Cargo"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="referencia">Persona de Referencia</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="referencia" placeholder="Persona de Referencia"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="referencia">Universidad</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="universidad" placeholder="Universidad"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="referencia">Nivel</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nivel" placeholder="Nivel"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="referencia">Especialidad</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="especialidad" placeholder="Especialidad"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="referencia">Inicio</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="inicio" placeholder="Inicio"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="referencia">Fin</label>
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fin" placeholder="Find"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="referencia">Idiomas</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="idiomas" placeholder="Idiomas"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="referencia">Escrito</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="escrito" placeholder="Escrito"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="referencia">Oral</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="oral" placeholder="Oral"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_form">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                    <div class="response_msg"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

POST.PHP PAGE Where I call the objects

```
include("class.php");

$load = new dbh();
$load->load();

$insert = new dbh();
$insert->insert($_POST);
```

My CLASS.PHP where I make the class

```
<?php
class dbh {

  private $servername;
  private $user;
  private $password;
  private $dbname;

  public function connect(){
    $this->servername = "localhost";
    $this->user = "root";
    $this->password = "";
    $this->dbname = "gcba";

    $conn = new mysqli($this->servername, $this->user, $this->password, $this->dbname);
    return $conn;
  }

  public function load(){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM datos";
    $result = $this->connect()->query($sql);
    $numrows = $result->num_rows;
    if ($numrows > 0) {
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row;
      }
      foreach ($data as $value) {
        echo $value['Nombre'];
      }
    }
  }

  public function insert($POST){
    $results = $this->connect();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO datos (Nombre, Apellido, Sexo, Estado_civil, Dni, Tel_fijo, Tel_celular, Calle,
                              Ciudad, Provincia, Pais,
                              Universidad, Nivel, Especialidad, Desde, Hasta,
                              Idiomas, Escrito, Oral,
                              Objetivo, Empresa, Actividad, Puesto, Categoria, Lugar,
                              Inicio, Fin, Area, Descripcion, Personas, Referencia) VALUES (?, ?, ?,
                              ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
                              ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $results->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssiiissssssssddsssssssssddsss", $POST["nombre"], $POST['apellido'], $POST['sexo'],
                            $POST['civil'], $POST['dni'], $POST['fijo'],
                            $POST['celular'], $POST['calle'], $POST['ciudad'],
                            $POST['provincia'], $POST['pais'], $POST['objetivo'],
                            $POST['empresa'], $POST['actividad'], $POST['puesto'],
                            $POST['categoria'], $POST['lugar'], $POST['desde'],
                            $POST['hasta'], $POST['area'], $POST['descripcion'],
                            $POST['personas'], $POST['referencia'], $POST['universidad'],
                            $POST['nivel'], $POST['especialidad'], $POST['inicio'],
                            $POST['fin'], $POST['idiomas'], $POST['escrito'],
                            $POST['oral']);

    $stmt->execute();
    var_dump(mysqli_query($results, $sql));
    var_dump($POST);
  }


}

 ?>
```

Comment: Let the driver tell you the error http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php.

Comment: Don't use `mysqli_query` with `mysqli_prepare/execute`. Get rid of the `query()` call.

Comment: What do you get with `var_dump($POST);`?

Comment: Check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) along the way.

Comment: Maybe you have one `s` to many?

Comment: @Michel Nah, 31 characters, table columns, and variables.

Comment: Sorry as I don't understand the column names, but are they in the correct order 'oral' is the last bind, but this column is in the middle of the column names of the INSERT.

Comment: @NigelRen I checked and ordered the columns, but nothing is coming to the DB
GrumpyCrouton vardump was just to check that information is going to the Variable and making sure the info was there, so the problem is the execute or bindparam

Comment: OK - I think your assuming that a bind param of type d is date - it's actually a double (from manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php - d corresponding variable has type double)

Comment: @NigelRen Updated, I wasnt even sure if that would have any impact, but just left all S and I for numbers.

Comment: What I did notice is that if I do something like $POST['area'] = 'something' it will save Something to DB.

Comment: So what does the `$POST` contain? Sounds like nothing..

Comment: @user3783243 I found the error I think. Phone number was INT in my database, and since it was a number, I was using one much bigger than the one expected by the INT reference. Therefore it was outside the scope of it. Im changing everything to VARCHAR in the DB. It seems the error comes when I use Chrome autocomplete, like its not getting the info, or its surpassing the 50 char limit